# Is there some lispy language that seamlessly integrates with Python?

Tags: python, clojure, lisp, scheme

Is there a language based on S-expressions with powerful macros that allows as seamless integration with Python as Clojure with JVM?

I want to try using such syntax and features while having access to all usual python libraries (including PyQt).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been working a project to do this: [psil](http://github.com/ghewgill/psil). I have a series of [blog posts](http://hewgill.com/journal/tags/psil) talking about what I've done. Here's the short [manifesto](http://hewgill.com/journal/entries/514-psil-manifesto):

> Psil is a new general-purpose programming language in the Lisp family of languages. Psil is implemented on top of Python, allowing easy access to existing Python libraries.
>
> - Best features from Lisp and Scheme
> - Complete language in its own right
> - Built upon the Python standard libraries
> - Strong interoperability with Python code

The reality hasn't quite caught up to the vision; for example I don't think there is a way to declare new classes in Psil code that can be used from Python. But at least for functions, it's mostly there.

Note that Psil is built completely on Python 3, and there is no Python 2 version. I don't know whether there is a PyQt for Python 3.

Comment: I hope PyQt for Py3 will be implemented soon enough after Py3 being stable.

Comment: The last serious commit is 2010-01-27. Will the project be continued someday to grow to thing like Clojure?

Comment: @Greg, nice project man, I like it ! What do you think of the name Pisp (Python + Lisp) instead of Psil (just suggesting)?

Comment: @Vi: That was my original ideal, but it's been on the back burner for a while. I'd like to see it grow.

Comment: @4bu3li: I originally thought Psil was kind of a clever name, but I'm open to other suggestions. :)

Comment: @Greg, "Psyl" is for "reversed lisp" or "anti-lisp". "Pisp" is for Python Lisp. Both names are not too overused. Also "pysp" is like "pisp", but more unique (6890 googles instead of 57700 for "pisp") and more Pythonish.

Comment: @Rayne: Thanks for the nudge, added one.

Answer (score 2):

While these aren't exactly what you're looking for, check:

[CLPython - an implementation of Python in Common Lisp](http://common-lisp.net/project/clpython/)

[(An ((Even Better) Lisp) Interpreter (in Python))](http://norvig.com/lispy2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/); it's a python-inspired language that runs on the CLR, with built-in support for full macros. If that's what you're missing from Lisp, give it a shot. A friend swears by it.